# Should i always use <img> tag in a <picture> tag?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

I am just learning HTML and I would like to know in which cases should I put the `<img>` tag inside `<picture>` tag.

Is it necessary to always do this:

```html
<picture>
      <img src="" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`<picture>` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `<img />` tag if it is just displaying an image but if you wanna display multiple images according to the screen size you can use `picture` tag to provide multiple different image sizes.

Comment: Would you recommend to use this method over `<img srcset="..." sizes="...">`?

Answer (score 4):

The `picture` tag allows you to have more flexibility with your image for more responsive images, and is similar to the `video` tag. The `img` tag is a child tag of the `picture` tag, and is used to embed still images. People use the `img` a lot more since they do not need a responsive images for everything, but rather still ones.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

A `<picture>` tag must always include an `<img />` tag, its the standard/fallback image. A `<picture>` tag then also can include any number of additional `<source />` images based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there are different versions and sizes for each photo on web pages, and we sometimes want to display a different size of photo based on different page sizes when designing Responsive pages. The `<picture>` tag makes it possible to display a different picture based on different conditions in order to avoid wasting resources and bandwidth:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="img-large.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-medium.jpg">
  <img src="img-small.jpg">
</picture>
```

if window width >= 900px

```
<source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="img-large.jpg">
```

if window width >= 600px

```
<source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-medium.jpg">
```

default

```
<img src="img-small.jpg">
```

In this tag, we put a `source` tag for each version of the image and specify the conditions under which this image should be displayed. At the end of it, we also put an `img` tag that will be displayed when none of the conditions are met. The browser automatically decides which images should be downloaded and displayed.